# iphone - undo or reverse kCATransitionPush to send image off screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I am currently sliding in an animated image from the right of the screen using CATransition:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = TRANSITION_DURATION;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
self.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:prefix duration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
```

My question is, how do I slide the image out?  Once the image animation cycles through, I want to send it off the screen in the direction from whence it came, i.e. TransitionToRight, but there doesn't seem to be such a transition type.  Please suggest how I might accomplish this reverse transition.

Here is how I might write it, if such a reverse transition existed:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeAnimatedImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:ANIMATION_DURATION];
```

and inside removeAnimatedImage, I would create another CATransition animation with this reverse direction to send it off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the kCATransitionFromLeft version of the push transition? It should be the inverse of FromRight.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I did try that, but it makes the image appear from the left, rather than disappearing to the right.

Comment: You need to push the "underneath" view from the left, not the image. This should have the effect you want.

Comment: I may not be understanding your intent, but fromLeft should work — you'd set the layer's image to nil (or whatever it was before your code above ran) so that the transition looks correct (what was there sliding off to the right). You can do that before or after adding the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution, but one hack is to either animate a change in frame bounds, or applying a translation transform animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:TRANSITION_DURATION];

if (enteredFromRight) {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(SCREEN_SPACE_WIDTH, 0);
} else {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-SCREEN_SPACE_WIDTH, 0);
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```